# Apache Flink - Sum and Group in a DataStream

Tags: mapreduce, stream, sum, apache-flink

Suppose I have records like this:

```
("a-b", "data1", 1)
("a-c", "data2", 1)
("a-b", "data3", 1)
```

How can I group and sum in Apache Flink, such that I have the following results when the input is a DataStream?

```
("a-b", ["data1", "data3"], 2)
("a-c", ["data2"], 1)
```

I only can think of either a solution by using {Time, Count}Windows and then grouping and applying transformations or by keeping the elements in an iteration stream (but this would need a lot of memory).

Regards, Kevin

Comment: You do not show any timestamps? Do you want to do this on the whole stream (ie, using a "infinite window")? If yes, you should use a custom operator state, and not a window. This this, iteration is not required either.

Comment: It should be done on the whole stream. I indeed not show any timestamps. How can it be done using a custom operator state?

Comment: You just create a key-value state and use it with map() (or flatMap()) that you apply after keyBy(). The state hold your current aggregate for each key. For each incoming tuple, your receive the current aggregate (ie, value lookup via key), update the aggregate, put is back into the state, and maybe send a result record (ie, the current aggregate of the key). See docs+examples https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/apis/streaming/state.html

Comment: Thank you Matthias! :-) However, the state can become very big, but that is an issue on itself. I can continue now :-).

Comment: You can configure different state backend. This allows to spill state to disc if it gets too big: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/apis/streaming/state_backends.html

Comment: Awesome! Thanks again :-).

Comment: @www.data-blogger.com Can you please share the solution? I have similar problem.